# Mi segundo while solo se ejecuta una vez o ninguna

Tags: java

Estoy intentando realizar un programa que cuente el numero de ceros totales de todos los inputs que realize el usuario hasta que introduzca un numero negativo. El error que ocurre es que en mi segundo while solo se ejecuta una vez a pesar de que tiene condiciones para que siga, haciendo que no me cuente los ceros de un numero que tenga varios ceros

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ej_4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num = 0;
    int ceros = 0;

    while (num >= 0) {
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
        num = sc.nextInt();

        if (num == 0)
            ceros++;
        
        if (num != 0) {
            while (num > 0){
                
                if (num % 10 == 0) {
                    ceros++;
                    num = num / 10;
                }
                
                else 
                    num = num / 10;
                
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Hubo un total de " + ceros + " ceros");
}
}
```

Comment: He probado tu código y funciona según lo que te piden, pueba ese break... y reiniciando el IDE y ejecutando como java application, recuerda cerrar los flujos, la clase Scanner debe ser cerrada antes de terminar el programa sc.close()

Comment: Pues claro que solo va a ejecutar una vez el `while` si al final se topa con un `break` que no está dentro de ningún condicional. Acostumbrarse a usar siempre las llaves, aunque sea para una sola línea.

Comment: El problema era el break que no lo habia quitado del codigo antiguo, ahora se ejcuta perfectamente, con el break no itera numeros de mas de 1 cero